# Hide when click outside div box, but if and only if mouse up and down start at outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

I have a login button (class = login-button), where if the button click, it will show a div box with login form in it (class = login-box) e.g:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.login-button').click(function(){
        $( ".login-box" ).show();
    });
});
```

and now, the way I hide the `.login-box` if user click outside is like this

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
    var targetbox = $('.login-box');
    if(!targetbox.is(e.target) && targetbox.has(e.target).length === 0){
        $('.login-box').fadeOut('fast');
    }
});
```

But the problem is on Chrome and Safari only (not Firefox), if user select a textbox as in would like to delete the text, highlight the text, but release the button outside the div, it will hide the login-box, but on Firefox it's not. 
My question is how to prevent this from happening. Is there anyway to hide the box if and only if user `click the mouse outside the box and release the mouse outside the box` ?

Comment: `click the mouse outside the box and release the mouse outside the box` Just use click instead of mouseup - what you described is what click does.

Comment: @Popnoodles if that is the case, as soon as I click login-button, it will show and then directly hide it again.

Comment: Prevent the event bubbling up or add the condition to ignore that in the document click function.

Comment: @Popnoodles Could you show me example code to prevent bubbling up? Thank you

Comment: sure, check the answer and demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use click instead of mouseup - what you described is what click does. Prevent the event bubbling up to stop the click of the button clicking document.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yrf32/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.login-button').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        $( ".login-box" ).show();
    });
});

$(document).click(function(e){
    var targetbox = $('.login-box');
    if(!targetbox.is(e.target) && targetbox.has(e.target).length === 0){
        $('.login-box').fadeOut('fast');
    }
});
```